# Inserting Form into table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert Form into Table, but `<form>` tag is not inserted (only input type).

```
$(function () {
    var table = document.getElementById("transport");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
    var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
    var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);
    cell1.innerHTML = "<form action='/Transport/Grid' id='paieska' method='post'>";
    cell2.innerHTML = "<br><br><input class=\"form-control\" id=\"slicplate\" name=\"slicplate\" placeholder=\"Valst. Nr.\" type=\"text\" value=\"\">";
    cell10.innerHTML = "</form>";
});
```

Comment: form start and end tags should be contained in one container.

Comment: Using tables for layout is considered oldskool

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above in the comments.

> `form` start and end tag should be contained within a container.

But you are starting it in one cell and closing in another. That will not work.

Instead you can do this:

```
cell1.innerHTML = "<form action='/Transport/Grid' id='paieska' method='post'>";
cell1.innerHTML += "<br><br><input class=\"form-control\" id=\"slicplate\" name=\"slicplate\" placeholder=\"Valst. Nr.\" type=\"text\" value=\"\">";
cell1.innerHTML += "</form>";
```

And so that you know, there are many better ways... This is kind of old school way..(as mentioned again in comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
var data =[];
function add(){

var fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value,
      lname= document.getElementById("lastname").value,
         email = document.getElementById("email").value,
         age = document.getElementById("age").value,
         mobile = document.getElementById("mobile").value,
         gen = gender1.checked?gender1.value:gender2.value,

         date = document.getElementById("date").value,
         adress = document.getElementById("address").value,
         city = document.getElementById("city").value,
          state = document.getElementById("state").value,


          zip = document.getElementById("zip").value,
        pan = document.getElementById("pan").value,
         tan = document.getElementById("tan").value,
          aadhar = document.getElementById("aadhar").value,
           obj = {name1:fname,name2:lname,mail:email,aged:age,num:mobile,gend:gen,tarrek:date,
            add:adress,place:city,stat:state,zpicode:zip,panc:pan,tanc:tan,aadharc:aadhar}
            data.push(obj);

            var table =  "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered margin' id='delet'>";
            table+= "<tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Email</th><th>Age</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Gender</th><th>Date</th><th>Address</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Documents</th><th>Zip</th><th>Pan</th><th>Tan</th><th>Aadhar</th></tr>";
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                    table+="<tr><td>"+data[i].name1+"</td><td>"+data[i].name2+"</td><td>"+data[i].mail+
                    "</td><td>"+data[i].aged+"</td><td>"+data[i].num+"</td><td>"+data[i].gend+
                    "</td><td>"+data[i].tarrek+"</td><td>"+data[i].add+"</td><td>"+data[i].place+
                    "</td><td>"+data[i].stat+"</td><td>"+data[i].zpicode+"</td><td>"+data[i].panc+
                    "</td><td>"+data[i].tanc+"</td><td>"+data[i].aadharc+
                    "</td></tr>"
                }
                table+="</table>";

                document.getElementById("table-data").innerHTML=table;

};
```

Comment: This does not answer to the question. Please refer the question again